# Rewrite root links [href="/foo.bar"] to [domain.com/~user/foo.bar]?

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I am hosting a website that has a `www.domain.com/~user/` root address.  Root HTML links such as `href="/foo.bar"` point to `www.domain.com/foo.bar` instead of `www.domain.com/~user/foo.bar`.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Surely, if the root directory of the site is `www.domain.com/~user`, then references to `/foo.bar` in that web site refer to `~user/foo.bar`?  And that is set in `httpd.conf`, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - In a perfect world it would be.  I'd have access to httpd.conf file if it were a perfect world, too.  Shoot - we probably wouldn't even have those files.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="http://www.domain.com/~user/" />` to the head of your HTML files, and remove that `.htaccess` stuff.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. `<base>` sets the root location for `href="foo.bar"`, not `href="/foo.bar"`.  I still need to use relative linking separate from root linking.